# How can I center an anchor link?

Tags: css

I have a link labeled `Get D1` which I need to center in the middle of the page. I tried text-align:center, but that works on the text itself and doesn't actually center the link in the middle of the page. Does anyone know the css trick for this?

```
<div id="allds">
    <div id="d1">
        <a href="http://someurl.com" id="d1link">Get D1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="d2">
        content of d2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you links displayed as blocks? Why center text isn't enough?

Comment: The text basicly **is** the link. How can the text be centered, but not the link?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#d1 { width:whatever; margin:0 auto; }
```

If you don't want to specify a width, you need to use an alternate technique.

Answer (score 35):

As simple as:

```
#d1link {display:block;text-align:center}
```

text-align:center doesn't work on inline elements. An anchor is an inline element by default.

Answer (score 12):

Here ya go:

```
#link-container {
    text-align: center;
}
#link {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

<div id="link-container">
    <a href="#" id="link">This is my link!</a>
</div>
```

That what you need?

Answer (score 0):

you can set margin-left of d1 to 50%...
but allds must have a spec width